# Move Part of uv island to new island, but keeping original seams

Tags: uv

I need to move the highlighted uv's down. This i can do fine but they will no longer be apart of that uv island, joining the new island at the bottom and creating new seams. Is there anyway to move them without creating new seams and keep them apart of the original island?
[image: Uv Map]
I tried spltting with Y but it creates new seams. This will be exported to srouce filmmaker and the new seam creates creases becuase of the way source light works with uv.
This is before i split, then after i split and joined with the lower island. Blender creates new seams and thats what im trying to avoid, if its possible
[image: Uv Map]
Thanks in advance